# Validation file upload CakePHP

Tags: validation, file, cakephp, arrays

How validate file upload in CakePHP?
When i wrote some like this:

```
var $validate = array(
    'file' => array(
        'select' => array(
            'rule' => array('selectFile'),
            'message' => 'There is no file!'),
        'type' => array(
            'rule' => array('typeFile'),
            'message' => 'Bad type!'),
        'size' => array(
            'rule' => array('sizeFile'),
            'message' => 'Bad with size!')));
```

Works only with the last validate, here 'size'. 
Maybe You know solution, for validation for files with many messages?

Comment: I create methods selectFile(), typeFile() and sizeFile(), for test all returns false, but order is: size, type and select. Why isn't order by select, type and the last size?

Answer (score 0):

try adding required=true to each of the 3 rules

Comment: I found solution: http://www.openwritings.net/content/execution-order-multiple-validation-rules